# Why the android application does not scale the image but hangs instead

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I am trying to get the scaled bitmap from an imageView because i need an image with height equal width so as to divide them later in equal smaller bitmaps. I am using the following piece of code:

```
 public void breakImage(View v)
    {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        Drawable d = imageView.getBackground();
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
        Bitmap image = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
        Bitmap scaledImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 240, 240, true);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
}
```

But the program gets stuck when it reaches the statement

```
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
```

Does anyone has an idea that what is the problem with this code?

Thanks in advance

Here is the LogCat:

```
01-03 04:47:57.078: D/dalvikvm(10411): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 52K, 52% free 2634K/5379K, external 1605K/2108K, paused 22ms
01-03 04:47:58.507: D/AndroidRuntime(10411): Shutting down VM
01-03 04:47:58.507: W/dalvikvm(10411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    ... 11 more
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at com.example.imagegallerydemo.MainActivity.breakImage(MainActivity.java:105)
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: I bet you're doing this in onCreate()?

Comment: No. I am doing it in a function which is called on click event. I have debugged the code. It reaches till the specified line but stucks there.

Comment: Ohh I am running it on real device..

Comment: You can still get the LogCat by enabling USB debugging from the phone and connecting your phone to USB.

Comment: Is it saying that the method is not being executed at all...?

Comment: So MainActivity.java:105 is BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) d); in your code?

Comment: No it is Bitmap image = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the cause of your error from your log:

```
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 04:47:58.531: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at com.example.imagegallerydemo.MainActivity.breakImage(MainActivity.java:105)
```

Which occurs because `d` is null, and `d` is null because `getBackground()` is null.

Are you sure you want `getBackground()`? This returns the background of the `ImageView`, not the image set with `android:src` or `setImageBitmap`,,`setImageDrawable`,`setImageResource` etc. To get that drawable use the `getDrawable()` method.